# Windows Phone 8 C# Random Ellipse generation

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new to building Windows Phone 8/8.1 apps (second app), and i'm having a pretty annoying problem.

What i'm trying to do, it I want to randomly generate an ellipse on my Canvas. But when i've generated the ellipse, I found out that the ellipse is always generated somewhere on the black line, as you can see in the image down below:

[image]

The code that i use to generate the ellipse is this:

```
    private void CreateDots()
    {

        Random Top = new Random();
        Random Left = new Random();

        int TopPos = Top.Next(0, 390); // screen height
        int LeftPos = Left.Next(0, 800); // screen width

        Ellipse Dot =new Ellipse();
        Dot.Name = "Dot";
        Dot.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0,0,0));
        Dot.Width = 50;
        Dot.Height = 50;

        Canvas.SetTop(Dot, TopPos);
        Canvas.SetLeft(Dot, LeftPos);

        Canvas.Children.Add(Dot);
    }
```

Does anybody now how to generate the ellipse anywhere on the screen, and not only on the black line?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create two `Random` instances like that. Create a single instance and then use it repeatedly.

Furthermore, persist the `Random` instance between calls to `CreateDots`. If you don't and you make calls in rapid succession, you may end up with two consecutive `Random` instances that have been seeded the same.

`Random` is by default seeded with the current time.

Your ellipses all tend to lie on the line where `Left` and `Top` have the same value because the two `Random` instances are created in rapid succession and almost always seeded with the same current time. When you then generate the `LeftPos` and `TopPos`, both calls to `Next` are starting from the same state.

Comment: Ah damn, really stupid of me for not seeing that. Thank you very much, it now works perfectly :)